# Making graphs with PyLab, doesn't plot the first value?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

Like the title says, I'm (learning to) plot with MatPlotLib/PyLab, and everything turns out fine, but the graph doesn't contain the first value in the list I'm plotting, and then causes all the values to be transformed one coordinate to the left. I've made a really simple program to illustrate this, and have provided an image of the final graph.

Windows 7, using NotePad++ but it makes the same result in IDLE as well.

Thanks for the help!

-Cory

```
from pylab import plot, show, axis

test = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
axis([1, 12, 0, 3])

plot(test, marker='o')
show()
```

[image: Test Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your [`axis`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html) to start from `1`, it should be from `0`. X-values begin from 0 by default.

```
from pylab import plot, show, axis
test = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
axis([0, 12, 0, 3])
plot(test, marker='o')
show()
```

[image]

However, if you from your first test value `1` to map for x=1, then provide the x values, like

```
from pylab import plot, show, axis
test = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
xvals = range(1, len(test)+1)
axis([1, 12, 0, 3])
plot(xvals, test, marker='o')
show()
```

[image]